# On Windows, why can't you overwrite the executable of a running application?

Tags: linux, windows

On linux systems, this causes no problems at all: the exe is loaded into ram when it is launched. The file can then disappear, be moved, etc. with no interaction whatsoever.

This doesn't seem to be the case on Windows. Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Related: [Windows Can But Won't](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.windowsconfidential.aspx), by Raymond Chen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From StackOverflow's [Locking Executing Files: Windows does, Linux doesn't. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196897/locking-executing-files-windows-does-linux-doesnt-why):

From [Oren Shemesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27333/oren-shemesh)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196908/225906):

> Linux has a reference-count mechanism, so you can delete the file
>   while it is executing, and it will continue to exist as long as some
>   process (Which previously opened it) has an open handle for it. The
>   directory entry for the file is removed when you delete it, so it
>   cannot be opened any more, but processes already using this file can
>   still use it. Once all processes using this file terminate, the file
>   is deleted automatically.
>
> Windows does not have this capability, so it is forced to lock the
>   file until all processes executing from it have finished.

From Perry Lorier's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/399984/225906):

> Linux does lock the files. If you try to overwrite a file that's
>   executing you will get "ETXTBUSY" (Text file busy). You can however
>   remove the file, and the kernel will delete the file when the last
>   reference to it is removed. (If the machine wasn't cleanly shutdown,
>   these files are the cause of the "Deleted inode had zero d-time"
>   messages when the filesystem is checked, they weren't fully deleted,
>   because a running process had a reference to them, and now they are.)